# Two C++ compilers disagree on whether my 'count_args' function is constexpr

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, constexpr

Here's a small function that counts the number of arguments you pass in:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr static int count_args() {
    return 0;
}

template<typename... SS>
constexpr static int count_args(int &v, SS & ... restargs)
{
    constexpr int rest = count_args(restargs...);
    return rest + 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a,b;
    constexpr int count = count_args(a,b);
    std::cerr << "count: " << count << std::endl; // Intended to print 'count: 2'
}
```

Two different compilers give two different results for this.  Under G++ 10.3.0, I get this error message:

```
> g++ -std=c++17 -o cx2.exe cx2.cpp
cx2.cpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr int count_args(int&, SS& ...) [with SS = {int}]':
cx2.cpp:15:16: error: 'restargs#0' is not a constant expression
   15 |  constexpr int rest = count_args(restargs...);
```

But under G++ 9.4.0, it compiles and runs as intended.  Could somebody clarify which compiler is "doing the right thing?"  Is this correct constexpr code, or is it invalid code?

Comment: You don't need `constexpr` for local variables in a constexpr function: `int rest = count_args(restargs...);` compiles w/o errors. `constexpr int rest` implies local static storage duration, thus is initialized in runtime on the first function call, hence can't be constexpr.

Comment: FWIW, you can reduce the function to: `template<typename... Ts> constexpr static std::size_t count_args(Ts&&...) { return sizeof...(Ts); }`

Comment: Just to clarify: originally, I was working on a fairly large program that compiles fine under 9.4.0.  I later tried compiling it under 10.3.0 and it failed.  I then took this large program and distilled it down to the bare minimum amount of code needed to generate the same compile error.  In this program, it is easy to rewrite it to not use a constexpr variable, but in the "real" program its derived from, I think I really do need to declare a variable constexpr.  Why doesn't that work?

Comment: The current versions of clang, gcc and MSVC all fail to compile this - live - https://godbolt.org/z/8zn44WWd6  and as @273K says removing `constexpr` fixes it.  You might need to add [language-lawyer] to get a definite answer as to why the change unless it was a just a g++ issue.

Comment: This has something to do with reference parameters (only works if the parameter isn't used in any way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From personal experience, older g++ compiler versions were generally sloppy at checking at if something was a constant expression. If something was optimized to become a constant even if it wasn't before, it was accepted without an error.

This is not a constant expression in C++11 to C++20. The reason is that references have to be initialized by something usable in a constant expression (which function arguments are not). The rationale being that you don't know whether `SS & ... restargs` are all valid references. For example, if you called `count_args` like `count_args(a, *static_cast<int*>(nullptr));`, it shouldn't have been a constant expression.

This is changed in C++23 by [P2280R4](https://wg21.link/P2280R4), which neither clang nor gcc have implemented yet, as seen here: https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx23 https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html. This makes `restargs....` "unknown references" that you can use in constant expressions, even though their initializer is not known.

Comment: Interesting. So is there any way to make a count_args function be a constexpr, short of just using the builtin sizeof...?

Comment: While `constexpr int rest = count_args(restargs...);` isn't a constant expression, it can be evaluated as part of a constant expression (when the initializer of the argument is known), so you can write `int rest = count_args(restargs...);`

Comment: Thanks especially for the reference to P2280R4.  That document contains a section labeled "wait, what?" (really, that's the chapter name) which delves exactly into this wierdness and explains really well what's going on.

Answer (score -2):

The bug is in this function

```
template<typename... SS>
constexpr static int count_args(int &v, SS & ... restargs)
{
    constexpr int rest = count_args(restargs...);
    return rest + 1;
}
```

You fix it by removing the `constexpr` that causes the compilation bug.

```
template<typename... SS>
constexpr static int count_args(int &v, SS & ... restargs)
{
    int rest = count_args(restargs...);
    return rest + 1;
}
```

This will compile and produce the proper result on GCC, Clang, and MSVC. Truth be told, I am unsure if it is a legitimate bug, defect in standard, or something else. But you can fix it without much problems.

I presume the issue is with static analysis of the template function, it is unable to tell that calling `count_args(restargs...)` will produce a `constexpr` as input variables aren't constexpr. Which normally shouldn't be an issue, as returning non-constexpr variable will not pose an issue at instantiating and calling of the template function at compile time.